# ASP.NET Configuration tool provider error

Tags: asp.net

I want to setup login roles for my application.
When I go to the ASP.NET Configuration Tool and Click on the Provider Tab, 
I select: Select a single provider for all site management data

I get this: AspNetSqlProvider 
When I click on the test hyperlink, I get this message:

Could not establish a connection to the database. 
If you have not yet created the SQL Server database, exit the Web Site Administration tool, use the aspnet_regsql command-line utility to create and configure the database, and then return to this tool to set the provider.

1) I created a ASPNETDB.MDF file in the APP_Data Folder
2) Ran the aspnet_regsql.exe tool that created the database ASPNETDB in my SQL Server
3) Edited the maching.config file for

```
<connectionStrings> 
  <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated  Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DIRECTORY|\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

In DIRECTORY, I replaced DIRECTORY with the actual path: C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\myProject

Don't know what else I am missing to get the ASP.NET Configuration Tool to work

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue :

1) Created a new website and copied the database it created in the `app_data` folder to `myproject 
  app_data` folder.

2) Copied the differences in the `webconfig` sections from the website to myproject.

Configuration tool now works correctly.